# sorting files by date in project explorer in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, sorting, package-explorer

Is it possible to show files in `package explorer` in the order of date they were created? I am using `eclipse juno` and I couldn't find any customize option in `view menu` of the project..

Currently the `package explorer` shows items in alphabetic order which cause me to search through the files to find the last modified project or java file. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment if I could to ask for clarification but don't have enough points...

I assume you don't have a team repository or you would have enabled its label decorations, which I know is available in svn.  Label decorations will show the team metadata associated with the files.  It won't have them sorted but with a small set, you can scan them manually.

In order for this to be useful with a large set, the sort would have to be across all folders/packages.  You could open up file explorer(assuming windows os), to the project folder, perform a search with filter of 'datemodified:'.  Now you may have to remove the semi-colon and add it again, hit enter.  That would sort the folders by date, then the files by date..across all folders.

Its ugly but it works (as far as I understand the question).  Good luck.